# Filling with values the area outside the cropped raster but still inside the masking polygon

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I have a problem with masking a raster by a polygon.

I would like to fill by values the area outside the clipped raster, but still inside the masking polygon (graphic example below).

[image]

The black field in the result raster represents the area outside the raster. It has been filled with a constant value, e.g. 0.

The problem I must solve in Python (without qgis or arcMap), possibly in Gdal via the command line. I have tried using the rasterio library.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem myself, so I am posting the code for others with the same problem.

1. I masked the raster with a polygon.
2. I then rasterised the masked polygon.
3. I performed a mosaic operation of the rasterised polygon and the cropped raster with the "max" parameter

```py
import numpy
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
from shapely import ops
from rasterio.merge import merge

image_size=1024
null_value=0
crs="+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
mask_polygon=ops.Polygon([[xmin,ymin+skok_y],[xmin+skok_x,ymin+skok_y],[xmin+skok_x, ymin],[xmin, ymin],[xmin,ymin+skok_y]])
big_raster_path='my_raster_path'

masked_raster=numpy.full((image_size, image_size), null_value).astype(numpy.uint16)


#saving the matrix to a tif file with georeferencing corresponding to the mask polygon
transform = from_origin(xmin, ymax, xres, yres)
new_dataset = rasterio.open(extract_path+'/temp/{0}.tif'.format(name), 'w', driver='GTiff',
                            height = masked_raster.shape[0], width = masked_raster.shape[1],
                            count=1, dtype=str(masked_raster.dtype),
                            crs=crs,
                            transform=transform)
new_dataset.write(masked_raster, 1)
new_dataset.close()
new_dataset=None

#mask "big raster" by polygon
with rasterio.open(raster) as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [grid], crop=True, filled=False)
    out_meta = src.meta

with rasterio.open("{0}/images/{1}.tif".format(extract_path, ids), "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)

#mosaic masked raster with rasterized polygon
src_files_to_mosaic =[rasterio.open(mask), rasterio.open(raster)]
mosaic, out_trans = merge(src_files_to_mosaic, method='max')
out_meta = src_files_to_mosaic[0].meta.copy()
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                        "height": mosaic.shape[1],
                        "width": mosaic.shape[2],
                        "transform": out_trans,
                        "crs": crs})
src_files_to_mosaic=None
with rasterio.open(raster, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(mosaic)
```